Wear os emulator synthetic data not working
I'm building an wearos app that uses heart rate and calories data, When I run the app with emulator, the heart rate data keeps giving the same data by starting from 60 -> 150 then restart.
I found that I can control these data with synthetic data commands but nothing seams to be working.
these are the commands that I tried:
adb shell am broadcast \
-a "whs.USE_SYNTHETIC_PROVIDERS" \
com.google.android.wearable.healthservices

adb shell am broadcast \
-a "whs.synthetic.user.START_WALKING" \
com.google.android.wearable.healthservices

My emulator os version is 4,
Any idea what could be the issue here?
